# Unable to showing codeigniter validation error

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here I have a validation with codeIgniter `form_validation` for customer name, which can prevent numerical digits as well as special characters and NULL.

And I have used a callback function which permit to stores only alphabetical characters within white spaces because name have always contains spaces.

Now the problem is, it can't be print their error message when validation goes false.

**Here is my callback function**

```
 public function customAlpha($str)
    {
        if ( !preg_match('/^[a-z .,\-]+$/i',$str) )
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('customAlpha', 'The {field} field may only contain alphabetical characters.');
            return false;
        } else {
            return True;
        }
    }
```

**Here is my controller code**

```
    public function customer_upd()
    {
        $original_value = $this->db->query("SELECT customer_email FROM customer WHERE id = ".$_POST['ctmr_upd_id'])->row()->customer_email ;
        if($_POST['cust_upd_email'] != $original_value) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('add_failed','Email id must be unique & valid email address.');
            $is_unique =  '|is_unique[customer.customer_email]';
        } else {
            $is_unique =  '';
        }
        $original_value = $this->db->query("SELECT customer_mobile FROM customer WHERE id = ".$_POST['ctmr_upd_id'])->row()->customer_mobile ;
        if($_POST['cust_upd_mobile'] != $original_value) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('add_failed','Mobile no must be unique & exact 10 digit numeric length. ');
            $is_phoneunique =  '|is_unique[customer.customer_mobile]';
        } else {
            $is_phoneunique =  '';
        }
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cust_upd_email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|trim'.$is_unique);
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cust_upd_mobile', 'Mobile', 'required|exact_length[10]|is_natural|trim'.$is_phoneunique);

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cust_upd_name', 'Customer', 'trim|required|min_length[3]|callback_customAlpha');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() ) {
            $userdata = $this->session->userdata();
            $userId = $userdata['id'];
            if (!$userId):
                redirect(site_url());
            endif;
            $data = array(
                'customer_name' => ucwords($_POST['cust_upd_name']),
                'birth_date' => $_POST['cust_upd_bd'],
                'anniversery_date' => $_POST['cust_upd_dom'],
                'customer_mobile' => $_POST['cust_upd_mobile'],
                'customer_email' => $_POST['cust_upd_email'],
                'status' => $_POST['cust_upd_status'],
                'address' => $_POST['ctmr_address'],
                'cat_type' => $_POST['file_cat']
            );
            $userdata = $this->session->userdata();
            $userId = $userdata['id'];
            $this->db->where('user_id', $userId);
            $this->db->where('id', $_POST['file_cat']);
            $this->db->where('cat_status', 'Enable');
            $get_file = $this->db->get('category');
            $res_file = $get_file->num_rows();

            if($res_file >0){
                $userdata = $this->session->userdata();
                $userId = $userdata['id'];
                $this->db->where('user_id', $userId);
                $this->db->where('id', $_POST['ctmr_upd_id']);
                $ctmr_upd = $this->db->update('customer', $data);
            } else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('edit_failed','Something went wrong.');
                redirect('customer/edit/'.$_POST['ctmr_upd_id']);
            }
            redirect(site_url() . '/customer');
        } else {
            redirect('customer/edit/'.$_POST['ctmr_upd_id']);
        }
    }
```

**Here is my view code**

```
                            <div class="item form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="name">Name <span
                                        class="required">*</span>
                            </label>
                            <?php
                            foreach ($qry as $res_sel_qry){
                            ?>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                <input id="onlyname" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" name="cust_upd_name"
                                       placeholder="" value="<?php echo $res_sel_qry['customer_name']; ?>"
                                       required="required" type="text">
                            </div>
                            <?php echo form_error('cust_upd_name'); ?>
                        </div>
```

There are many things that are going to validate and working fine expect customer name(doesn't showing there error message).

Please guide me, where I'm going wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the redirect func

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() ) {
        $userdata = $this->session->userdata();
        $userId = $userdata['id'];
        if (!$userId):
            redirect(site_url());
        endif;
        $data = array(
            'customer_name' => ucwords($_POST['cust_upd_name']),
            'birth_date' => $_POST['cust_upd_bd'],
            'anniversery_date' => $_POST['cust_upd_dom'],
            'customer_mobile' => $_POST['cust_upd_mobile'],
            'customer_email' => $_POST['cust_upd_email'],
            'status' => $_POST['cust_upd_status'],
            'address' => $_POST['ctmr_address'],
            'cat_type' => $_POST['file_cat']
        );
        $userdata = $this->session->userdata();
        $userId = $userdata['id'];
        $this->db->where('user_id', $userId);
        $this->db->where('id', $_POST['file_cat']);
        $this->db->where('cat_status', 'Enable');
        $get_file = $this->db->get('category');
        $res_file = $get_file->num_rows();

        if($res_file >0){
            $userdata = $this->session->userdata();
            $userId = $userdata['id'];
            $this->db->where('user_id', $userId);
            $this->db->where('id', $_POST['ctmr_upd_id']);
            $ctmr_upd = $this->db->update('customer', $data);
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('edit_failed','Something went wrong.');
            redirect('customer/edit/'.$_POST['ctmr_upd_id']);
        }
        redirect(site_url() . '/customer');
    } else {
        //redirect('customer/edit/'.$_POST['ctmr_upd_id']);
    }
```

Comment: then what about else part when validation goes false ??

Comment: why the down vote?
The error message will not appear because you are redirecting it to a page.
Try putting this on the false part. Lets see if error message will pop up.
`var_dump( validation_errors() ); die();`

Comment: stackoverflow requires minimum 125 reputation for down vote, buddy

Comment: the error is: string(67) "

The Customer field must be at least 3 characters in length.
"

Comment: so if you remove that dump code and try again, will that error message show in the view?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
```

With

```
<div class="<?php if (form_error('cust_upd_name') != null) { echo ' has-error'; } ?>">
```

In your css

```
.has-error {
color : red;
}
```